# UWP MVVM binding to TextBox and passing back value

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, uwp

I am trying to get the content of a TextBox updated using Binding in a MVVM environment. When a Button receive focus, it passes a value, and that value should be reflected in the TextBox. I seem to have the first part right, however seems to be struggling at passing the value..
I know the question about MVVM has been asked before (including by myself), but I really cannot get it, for some reasons..

So I start with my model:

```
public class iText : INotifyPropertyChanged

{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Text)));
        }
    }
```

I then continue with my ViewModel:

```
private iText _helper = new iText();
public iText Helper
{
    get { return _helper; }
    set
    {
        _helper = value;
    }
}
```

The XAML page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <scan:ModelDataContext x:Key="ModelDataContext" x:Name="ModelDataContext"/>
</Page.Resources>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Helper.Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I then try to update the Text from MainPage.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPageViewModel iText { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        iText = new MainPageViewModel();
    }

    private void btn_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var str = "test"
        iText.Helper.Text = str;
    }
```

I could really appreciate if someone could tell me what I do wrong, and where. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: The code you posted, bizarre identifier naming notwithstanding, would work fine if found in a complete code example. So whatever your problem, it's in the code you didn't bother to show. Please fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainPage constructor, try setting the datacontext to your ViewModel.
Something like...

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    iText = new MainPageViewModel();
    this.dataContext = iText;
}
```

Comment: Bingo, that's exactly what was missing.. :) Thanks so much.